# Graph not going full length latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

My graph stops almost in the middle of the x-axis. I want it to go the full length of the axis, but i dont know how.

my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} 
\usepackage{siunitx}


\title{Plots}
\author{scott}
\date{October 2022}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h]

    \centering
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:my_label}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    [xmin=0, xmax=12, 
    ymin=0, ymax=0.50, 
    axis lines =left, 
    xlabel=$R_L(k\ohm)$, 
    ylabel=$U_{RL}(V)$]
    
    \addplot[blue]
    {x/(1.10664+x)*0.464)};
    \end{axis}
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE>! Please extend your code fragment to complete small document beginning with`\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The current code yields an error about `\ohm` being undefined. Are you using siunitx, and how?

Comment: Yes im using siunitx, added it now to the code :)

Comment: You have two errors: (i) wrong use of `siunitx` units and (ii) not define domain of function,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in comment, your MWE have not defined function domain and wrong use of `siunitx`: Correct and slightly improved MWE can be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:my_label}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    [xmin=0, xmax=12,
    ymin=0, ymax=0.50,
    axis lines =left,
    xlabel=$R_L(\unit{\kilo\ohm})$,
    ylabel=$U_{RL}(V)$
    ]

\addplot +[domain=0:12, mark=none]{x/(1.10664+x)*0.464)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried to use domain but I completely forgot using "=" in between domain and the range.

Comment: @Scott, it happen .... BTW, that your question will be marked as solved, you may consider to accept it ;-)